# ZFS receive freezes on host

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I am experiencing an issue if I want to do a `zfs receive` on FresBSD 11.3. I start it using `zfs receive -vF destpool@snap1 < snapshot.zfsdump`. The sending part works fine but the receive says:

```
receiving full stream into destpool@2019-07-27
```

And then the whole machine is getting laggy. At first I can still use the mouse, but I cannot for example establish a new SSH connection into it. I also cannot abort the command in the terminal using crtl-C.

I have tried debugging it by looging at suspicious dmesg messages, but there was nothing. Also I tried recreating the zfs pool on the destination disk.

What I want to achieve is to backup my ZFS root system onto another pool in the same machine.

It seems similar to [zfs send -i / receive stalling](https://serverfault.com/questions/507587/zfs-send-i-receive-stalling) but this is FreeBSD, not Solaris and it has not fully investigated then, too.

I am grateful for any ideas.

**Update**
I have made some more experiments. When receiving small datasets it works, however when I tried to transfer a 2 GB dataset the machine stalled again.

```
# zfs receive -vd zfsroot < /tmp/test.zdump
receiving full stream of zroot/tmp@2019-07-24 into zfsroot/tmp@2019-07-24
received 4.39MB stream in 1 seconds (4.39MB/sec)
```

The 2 GB snapshot did not finish.